# How far could we see (horizontally), floating inside the acid clouds of Venus at 56 km and at 51 km height above the surface?

Tags: atmosphere, planetary-science, venus

[image: Venus cloud system1]
Screenshot of Fig. 4 in the article [The microphysics of the clouds of Venus: Results of the Pioneer Venus Particle Size Spectrometer Experiment](https://www.astrobio.k.u-tokyo.ac.jp/imamura/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/Knollenberg_Hunter_1980.pdf)

From the [Wikipedia section about the troposphere of Venus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Venus#Troposphere):

> As manned ships sent to Venus would be able to compensate for differences in temperature to a certain extent, anywhere from about 50 to 54 km or so above the surface would be the easiest altitude in which to base an exploration or colony,...

That section shows a height/temperature/atmospheric pressure table with at **50 km height** a temperature of **75⁰ C** and a pressure of **1.066 atm.**, and at **55 km height, 27⁰ C and 0.531 atm.** respectively.

That makes me wonder what would be easier manageable for a manned ship, 75⁰ C at the right pressure or 0,5 atm. at the right temperature ?

Moreover, as can be seen on the image above, from **51 to 55 km height** the mass loading of the sulfuric acid droplets would be about **11 mg/m³**, but at about **55 km** there's a sharp  decline to **3-4 mg/m³.**
For comparison, the permissible exposure limit on the basis of a 8 h/day, 40h/week work schedule is **1 mg/m³** for sulfuric acid.

**Edit:** In the meantime I've learned that to determine the visibility it's more appropriate to use **the graph of the extinction coefficient** from the image above.

So what would be the horizontal visibility at **56 km** with a **1 km⁻¹** extinction coefficient and at **51 km** with a **3-4 km⁻¹** extinction coefficient measured inside the clouds ?
Is it possible to calculate the visibility with the [formulae presented in this article](https://biral.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/WP-Introduction-to-atmospheric-visibility-estimation-DOC101478.00A.pdf) and then "translate" it to the atmospheric conditions on Venus ?
And could we see the contour of the Sun at those heights ?
(The last question need not to be answered in order to get an accepted answer)

Comment: The answer lies down this path. This work is at the surface of Venus, you would have to determine the atmospheric extinction coefficient for the expected chemistry at those altitudes, and that should give you the visibilities.  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/215745782_Evaluation_of_the_atmospheric_extinction_on_Venus_at_different_wavelengths

Comment: There are people in the Himalaya living at 4000 meters or higher. The temperature is colder than 25 and there is only about half a bar of air pressure there. If my options were 1 bar and 75 C or 0.5 bar and 25 C, I would go for the 25 C and 0.5 bar.

Comment: You refer to a "sharp decline" in properties over a few kilometers. This is not a feature of the atmosphere itself, but just due to the Pioneer probe passing through the edge of a cloud. That will be different at any other position or time.

Comment: @asdfex That decline happens in the transition from the middle cloud region to the upper cloud region. I think the edges of clouds are much higher, at the top of the upper cloud region.